# Laravel: how to parse string to json

Tags: laravel

I've created this code from laravel:

```
public function findConfig($id)
    {
        $config = DB::table('configuration')
                    ->join('model', 'model.configuration_id','=', 'configuration.id')
                    ->select('configuration.id','configuration.description', 'model.name','configuration.price')
                     ->where('configuration.id','=', $id)
                    ->get();

                     $encode = json_encode($config, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                     $response = Response::make($encode, 200);
                     $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                     return $response;
    }
```

then the return is somehow like this

```
[{
"id": "1",
"description": "{\"item\":[{'colours\":[\"red\",\"blue\",\"green\"]},{\"motors\":[ {\"name\":\"450W/48V\",\"price\":\"2,000\"},{\"name\":\"550W/48V\", \"price\":\"3,000\" }] } ]}",
"name": "k5-A",
"price": "300000"
},
{
"id": "1",
"description": "{\"item\":[{'colours\":[\"red\",\"blue\",\"green\"]},{\"motors\":[ {\"name\":\"450W/48V\",\"price\":\"2,000\"},{\"name\":\"550W/48V\", \"price\":\"3,000\" }] } ]}",
"name": "r-A",
"price": "300000"
}
]
```

How can I remove the slashes and instead of `string` as return type, it should be in JSON?

Comment: I know that's not the answer to your question, but in general its a bad idea to store json in your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lukasgeiter said, generally it isn't a good idea to store json in a db. It may get difficult to filter by that field.
If you decide to do so, and need to get the decoded data, you can use an accessor in the model. I don't know if it is the best practice. If the description is saved in the db as a json you can do this: 
For the "configuration" table you may have a "Configuration" model (The official Laravel website recommends to name the table in plural, and the model in it's singular, like: table -> configurations and the model configuration). In that file you can add this:

```
public function getDescriptionAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

Now, the description field is returned as an array.
You can see more about accessors and mutators here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: I see. thank you for that. but anyway. i've already come up with a solution for this. Cheers!!